# Try to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel with VB.NET in Linux

Tags: excel, linux, vb.net

I would like to use a macro on several excels automatically every day on my linux (debian 9). so I looked for a little bit, and I found that it is possible using VB.NET.

After added microsoft package I installed dotnet-sdk

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

then create my project with `dotnet new console -lang VB`

I modified Program.vb to that:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        ProcessFiles
    End Sub
End Module

Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

    Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/path/xlsx/"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        DoWork( wb )
        wb.Close( SaveChanges:=True )
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Sub DoWork(wb As Excel.Workbook)
    With wb
        .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select
        .Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        .Rows("1:1").Select
        .Selection.AutoFilter
        .ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$999999").AutoFilter( Field:=1 , Criteria1:="<>*2018*" )
        .Range("A2:L999999").Select
        .Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        .Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        .ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$999999").AutoFilter( Field:=1 )
        .Rows("1:1").Select
        .Selection.AutoFilter
        .Range("A2").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

And now, i'm trying run with `dotnet run` and I have the error : `error BC30002: The type 'Excel.Workbook' is not defined.`

I've found a lot of answer that give the good import :
`Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`
but this is not enough. I also found solutions using Visual Studio, but I do not have it and don't want to ...

Thank's for your help

Comment: Hmm, COM Interop in *nix. And without Visual Studio, just hardcore-command-line-*nix->(Win)COM->(Win)Interop. Sounds fun.

Comment: there are (used to be?) good Excel conversion libraries available to the `perl` language. But that is all I can offer.I don't have information about the name, or versions. Sorry and Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel Interop layer requires (wait for it . . . ) Excel. 8-)

Unless you have found a copy of Microsoft Office for Linux and all the Magic that implements the COM interface, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to [Terry Carmen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1951463/terry-carmen) for his answer.
We've found another answer without use VB and Excel macro for our needs.
In the case where we would have been forced to use VB and Excels, we could have done it under macOS.